# Apex Test - Instantiate new Controller

Tags: apex, apex-code

I am trying to instantiate a new controller. But every syntax I have tried shows an error.

Here is my code:

Class:

```
public  class MyNewCaseController {
    
    public string filterId {get; set;}
    
    public MyNewCaseController(ApexPages.StandardController  ctrl){
        string filter = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('filterId');
        if (filter != null)
            filterId = filter;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@isTest
public without sharing class MyNewCaseListControllerTest {
    
    @isTest
    public static void testMyNewCaseController (){
        // Instantiate a new controller with all parameters in the page
        MyNewCaseListController controller = new MyNewCaseListController.MyNewCaseListController(ApexPages.StandardController ctrl);
 
    // Do something
    }
}
```

I get the error “Invalid type: CommunitiesCaseListController.CommunitiesCaseListController”.

If I try just

```
MyNewCaseListController controller = new MyNewCaseListController();
```

I get Constructor not defined: [MyNewCaseListController].()

If I try

```
MyNewCaseListController.MyNewCaseListController();
```

I get “Invalid type: MyNewCaseListController.MyNewCaseListController”

If I try

```
MyNewCaseListController controller = new MyNewCaseListController.MyNewCaseListController(ApexPages.ctrl);
```

I get “Invalid type: MyNewCaseListController.MyNewCaseListController”

What am I doing wrong?